# Apollo Optimistic UI - how does it handle an optimistic update after an optimistic create?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, optimistic-ui

Trying to understand conceptually how Optimistic UI works, appreciate any help!

Scenario:

- We send a mutation to create a new `User` "John" --> **Request A**
- We leverage the Optimistic UI feature to immediately return 'fake' data for "John"

  - Fake "John" has  the `Id` field: "FakeId10001"
- Before we get a response from **Request A**, we send another mutation to update "John"'s `name` to "Johnny" --> **Request B**
- **Request A** finally gets processed, and creates a `User` "John" with `Id` "10001"
- The server now tries to process **Request B**

Presumably, **Request B** would try to update the `User` with `Id` "FakeId10001" and fail, since that user does not exist.

Does Apollo wait for **Request A** to respond before sending **Request B**, or anything else to handle this behaviour?